# How can I select a specific element on a page when there is so many of that element? Selenium webdriver python;

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Essentially what I am trying to do is select just the "Reply" box which circled in red, but there are many of these in the page overall. My aim is to be able to select the first "Reply" box on every page. How can I select just the first reply box for every post (with this link just being an example)?

Currently this doesn't seem to work:

```
reply = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content']/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/article/div/aside/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[7]/button/span/img")
reply.click()
```

Many thanks.

Comment: In addition to the existing answers, maybe check out some browser extensions that help you select elements, e.g. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selectorgadget/mhjhnkcfbdhnjickkkdbjoemdmbfginb?hl=en

Comment: While I believe most people to have good intentions, I can't help but notice you're trying to find the "Reply" button in a forum. Please note that SO doesn't tolerate people who use the communities knowledge for evil, e.g. spam.

Comment: I don't appreciate being accused of spam when my goal is to help customers on a community forum. In the future, try to do your own research before throwing accusations at people.

Comment: I wasn't trying to accuse you of anything and i'm sorry if my comment made you feel that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First way:**
The XPath to locate any of that replay buttons is

```
//button[@title="Reply"]
```

So the XPath to locate the first replay button is

```
(//button[@title="Reply"])[1]
```

So you can simply

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//button[@title="Reply"])[1]').click()
```

**Second way:**
With the XPath above you can retrieve a list of all the replay buttons and then get the first element in the list and click on it as following:

```
replay_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[@title="Reply"]')
replay_buttons[0].click()
```

You can use css_selector instead of XPath here as well:

```
replay_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('button[title="Reply"]')
replay_buttons[0].click()
```

Comment: so it has worked so far in selecting the first reply button, do you think there would be a way, to also send the keys "@username" after pressing reply, so the person knows I am replying to them? In the case of the link above: https://community.giffgaff.com/d/33277735-over-charging , I want to reply to user "1prophet1" in this example they are the first original poster. Is there a way to reply with the whoever the first poster's name was without having to manually input their actual name?

Comment: Are you asking about the new window opened to login to the system with username and password fields and login button there?

Comment: I see. I think this is an another separate question while stackoverflow asks users to ask only 1 question per question. So please accept the answer here and I will try to answer that question separately

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the page i saw that the class name of this button is: `<button class="Button Button--link">`

So you can use `driver.find_elements_by_class_name('Button Button--link')` ,
which returns a list of all the buttons.